# How to remove/rename file in clearcase with CM API?

Tags: clearcase

How to remove/rename file in clearcase with CM API?

I can't find any useful methods under CcFile or CcDirectory... any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CM Api means ClearCase 8.x or more](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.team_api.doc/topics/c_introduction.htm).
The ClearCase CM server API extends the WVCM (Workspace Versioning and Configuration Management) API, which is a standard [Java API for configuration management](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=147).
Only CC 8.0.1.6 supports dynamic *and* snapshot views.

Considering [`cleartool mv`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mv.htm) is *also* available for `rcleartool`, using that would be easier than the CM API.

However, as noted by [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62427098/how-to-remove-rename-file-in-clearcase-with-cm-api/62428269?noredirect=1#comment110417104_62428269):

> The CM API is actually able to perform checkouts, mkelems, etc.
>   `rcleartool` and `CTE` actually use CM API, with `rcleartool` being the more "pure" CM API application.
>   So, in 90% of usecases, if `rcleartool` can do it, a CM API application should too.

Comment: @meteoriteliu I agree. This does not seem supported. What ClearCase version are you using? On which OS (client and server side)?

Comment: I‘m using clearteam remote client v9.0 on windows, server side not sure. maybe i will try the command line rcleartool

Comment: @meteoriteliu Yes, I have edited the answer to add `rcleartool mv`

Comment: @meteoriteliu Can you please also post this question through your normal support channels to IBM/HCL? Metric-driven support and development mean that it is very hard to argue that we need to improve documentation or redo the tutorials for the API if we don't have the numbers to back up the statement that people are using the API...

Comment: @meteoriteliu the CM API is actually able to perform checkouts, mkelems, etc. Rcleartool and CTE actually use CMAPI, with rcleartool being the more "pure" CMAPI application. So, in 90% of usecases, if rcleartool can do it, a CMAPI application should too.

Comment: @BrianCowan actually I'm not sure how to ask this through "normal support channels" as my company never teach me how... you seems like working on clearcase project, can you just share some idea here?

Comment: I work in support @ HCL, meaning that anything in any detail has to have a support case associated with it. Unfortunately, I do not know what company you work for, or whether they still have a support contract. The CMAPI documentation is somewhat light in key areas, and the tutorials are not in the current infocenter (they're in the 7.1.x infocenter which is amazingly still available).